# python- writing multiple header to csv file

Tags: python, loops, csv, header

I would really appreciate helping me to fix this error by writing the header only once

```
try:
    with open(save_folder + 'all.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile_new:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile_new, delimiter=',')
        for i in range(np.shape(csv_data)[0]): #Count through all rows in list and save to csv
            spamwriter.writerow(csv_data[i][:])

    print("Processing of file named {} is completed.".format(file))
except PermissionError:
    print("\n--- PERMISION ERROR ---")
    print("CSV FILE NAMED: {} COULD NOT BE PROCESSED".format(patient_id + '.csv'))
    print("PLEASE ENSURE THIS SPREADSHEET IS NOT BEING USED BY ANOTHER PROGRAM\n")
```

thats how my file look like
[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fT58.png)

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what your problem is. What is the current behavior of your code and what do you want to achieve? What does your csv_data look like?

Comment: my header row is repeated with every time it opens the file

Comment: From what I can see, in your code example the csv file is opened only once. Is this a function you call multiple times for different csv_data lists. If so, do each of them contain the same header (which then likely is the source of your problem)? Please give all the information that is needed to understand your problem.

Comment: Yes ,, I'm uploading this to the cluster, header should be the same for all data ,, I'm calling file by file to read and do some calculation and then write to the csv file

Comment: csv_data = [['Patient ID', 'Age', 'XML file_Name', 'Mean_RR', 'MeanBPM', 'MedianRR', 'MedianBPM', 'MinRR', 'MinBPM', 'MaxRR',
            'MaxBPM', 'SDNN', 'RMSSD', 'nn50', 'pnn50'] ]
# for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir): #Loop through all files in directory
#     for file in files:



file = sys.argv[1]
if file[-3:] == 'xml':

Answer (score 0):

```
    with open(save_folder + 'all.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile_new:

    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile_new, delimiter=',')
    count = 0
    header_row =[]
    for i in csv_data: #Count through all rows in list and save to csv
        other_rows = []
        if count == 0:
            header_row.append(i)
            spamwriter.writerow(header_row)
            count = count+1
        other_rows.append(i)
        spamwriter.writerow(other_rows)
```

Comment: This piece of code has no effect. The only thing it does is write the row into a different temporary list if count is 0 before writing it into the csv. There is effectively no difference in the result whether count is 0 or not.